# EPPlus Print Area - column definition

Tags: c#, printing, epplus

I want to define a list of columns as an Excel PrintArea (by EPPlus, c#). I can define interval (first and last column of area) but I don't know how to define separate columns (for instance: A, C, F, G).

I can set interval like this:

```
listSheet.PrinterSettings.PrintArea = listSheet.Cells["A,G"];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`PrintArea` is an `ExcelRangeBase` so you can set it link any other range:

```
listSheet.PrinterSettings.PrintArea = listSheet.Cells["A:A,G:G"];
```

Comment: Close - it's `listSheet.PrinterSettings.PrintArea = listSheet.Cells["A:G"];`

Comment: @CADbloke Wont that select ALL columns between A and G? (what the op was asking to avoid).

Comment: Whoops. You are right. Perhaps I should avoid word-skipping when reading these things. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: If I have a column that is autofit, this doesn't work for me... :(